# Need to Add new Column (ColumnAxColumnB) and inset new row at bottom for final amount (New Column)

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, multiplication

```
SELECT  
   CAST(CreationDate AS DATE) AS DateField, QuantityLeft, Cost
FROM         
   vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation
GROUP BY 
   CAST(CreationDate AS DATE), QuantityLeft, Cost
ORDER BY 
   DateField

SELECT
   SUM(Quantityleft * Cost) As Dollargoods
FROM
   vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation
GROUP BY 
   ROLLUP (QuantityLeft, Cost);
```

1. When I group by dates bc I need 1 entry due to 3shifts, it works independently. But when I join the 2nd select statement, my report does not work.  Please help
2. When I perform `SUM(Quantityleft *Cost) As DollarGoods` and `GROUP BY ROLLUP (Quantityleft, Cost)`, it fails and I loose the grouping by dates. I need the calculated 'dollardgoods' working with grouping dates because our system has 3 shifts per day and I need the day to be one entry?
3. I need to insert a row for a Total of DollarGoods. I'm using `COMPUTE SUM(Quantityleft), SUM(Cost)` but this does not work as it gives me another query window but not in the same query and I can't retrieve in my crystal reporting.

How should I approach this? I'm using SQL Server.

```
SELECT
    CAST(vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.CreationDate AS DATE) AS Date,
    vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.Item,
    vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.SerialNumber, 
    vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.QuantityLeft,
    vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.Cost,
    vgMfiItems.Description1,
    vgMfiItems.Specification1, 
                  vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.LotId
FROM         vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation INNER JOIN
                  vgMfiItems ON vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.Item = vgMfiItems.Item
GROUP BY CAST(vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.CreationDate AS DATE), 
         vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.Item, vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.SerialNumber, 
         vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.QuantityLeft, vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.Cost,
         vgMfiItems.Description1, vgMfiItems.Specification1, 
          vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.LotId
HAVING (vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.Item LIKE 'G%')
   AND (vgMfiItems.Specification1          = 'GUMMY_BULK')
   AND (vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation.QuantityLeft > '0')
ORDER BY Date
COMPUTE SUM(Quantityleft), SUM(Cost)
```

`

Comment: Please add formatting to your question and give some examples of what you want to achieve. Your question is a pain in the eye.

Comment: how do I do that? sorry Im new but need help

Comment: I already did it. Use Ctrl-K to format your code, otherwise stuff just text-wraps.

Comment: I need answers and you guys are editing my query but not helping me achieve what I need.  How do I put the above 2 select statments together.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this in `crystal reports` then don't complicate query too much instead do your grouping and calculations in crystal reports.

1. Make database connection in crystal reports and in `Add Command` paste the below query and click `Ok`

   ```
   SELECT  
      CAST(CreationDate AS DATE) AS DateField, QuantityLeft, Cost
   FROM         
      vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation
   ```
2. Go to the design and create a group by using option `Insert Group`. In dropdown select `DateField` and click ok.
3. Now place `QuantityLeft`,`Cost` in details.
4. Create a formula `@Calculate` and write below code.

   ```
   Quantityleft * Cost
   ```
5. Now insert summary for all fields in `group footer` using `Right Click on filed --> insert --> Summary`. Now you can get summary for required values.

Edit---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    SELECT
   DateField, QuantityLeft, Cost,SUM(total) As Dollargoods
FROM
   (SELECT  
   CAST(CreationDate AS DATE) AS DateField, QuantityLeft, Cost,(Quantityleft * Cost) as total
FROM         
   vgIcoInventoryLotByLocation) t
GROUP BY 
   DateField
ORDER BY 
   DateField
```

Comment: Thanks..I just tried it..Our Crystal report in tied to Automated Task Manager called GTA...I don't have those fields you are talking about in Crystal...I can only paste SQL commands..it wont recognize Java as well...can you help me write the script and I can try it from there??

Comment: I am not well versed with queries but tried to provide you the solution... see my edit for the `query`. If it is useful use it else I apologize as I can't help you beyond this.

Comment: Thank you anyhow..it didn't work...but really appreciate your help..god bless you...